# Search capable task/program switcher for Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, productivity

I am looking for a program similar to [Switcher 2.0](http://insentient.net/) which can make me more efficient when looking for programs/windows I know I have open. I have tried this app but it seems slow and buggy under Windows 10, having been initially released for Vista.

Ideally I should be able to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (or some configurable hotkey) and for instance start writing 'sp' and press enter to jump to my Spotify window.

Anyone know of a program providing this capability for Windows 10? My googling thus far has proved unsuccessful.

Comment: You can configure your Windows so that the taskbar only has running programs (its default behaviour is that it is also used as a start bar - one of the worst design decisions made in Win7 and kept in later versions: one indicator for two different kinds of functionality)

Comment: What's your budget?

Comment: @ThomasWeller I have not really considered it, but I would say for a program I could test first and install on multiple machines up to 70$ maybe.